# Laravel + jquery + ajax (Buscar preguntas frecuentes)

Tags: javascript, laravel, ajax

tengo una tabla en la base de datos de Preguntas y respuestas, y en la vista tengo tengo un input, y agregue una funcion keypress al input, de tal forma que al ir escribiendo, automaticamente se vallan pintando las preguntas  que concuerdan con lo que se esta escribiendo en el input.

al entrar por primera ves a la vista, por defecto me cargan todas las preguntas que estan en la base de datos, lo realizo de la siguiente forma:

```
@foreach ($PreguntasCategoria->preguntasrespuestas as $preguntasrespuesta)
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-header" id="faq{{$loop->index + 1}}">
        <button class="panel-link py-2 pl-1 px-2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse{{$loop->index + 1}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse{{$loop->index + 1}}">{{$preguntasrespuesta->pregunta}}</button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse{{$loop->index + 1}}" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-administracion">
        <div class="panel-body px-3">
            <p>{!! $preguntasrespuesta->respuesta !!}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

controlador:

```
public function buscarpreguntasfrecuentes($palabra){
    $res = PreguntasRespuestas::select('*')
            ->where("pregunta","LIKE","%{$palabra}%")
            ->get();

    return response()->json($res);
}
```

vista, input:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" name="search_faq_input" id="search_faq_input" autofocus placeholder="Buscar alguna pregunta" onkeypress="buscar()">
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button type="button" title="Filtrar preguntas" onclick="buscar()"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

funcion javascript:

```
<script>
    function buscar(){
        consulta = $("#search_faq_input").val();
        console.log(consulta);

        //hace la búsqueda
        var url = '{{ route("front.buscarpreguntasfrecuentes", ":consulta") }}';
        url = url.replace(':consulta', consulta);
        $.ajax({
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            url: url,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);

                },error:function(){
                    console.log("Error");
                    console.log(data);
                }
        });
    }
</script>
```

actualmente funciona, la funcion me retorna un array, con su pregunta y respuesta, ahora quiero pintar esos datos en la vista, sin necesidad de refrescar, como puedo hacerlo? se que para eso se usa jquery, pero no se como hacerlo.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Crea un div con un id único donde vaya a ir la lista de las preguntas/respuestas, y luego usa selectores de jquery y el método html() para incluirlo en el div como tu quieras. Si cuando lo hagas tienes problemas actualiza la pregunta con los nuevos datos y errores. Aqui no hacemos tareas (o no deberiamos), debes hacerlo tu, lo siento.  Revisa [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento de este sitio, gracias.

Comment: en ningun momento pedi que me hicieran la tarea, solo estoy pidiendo directrices de como trabajar el jquery cuando retorna un array.

Comment: Y es lo que te he dado en mi comentario anterior, y espero que te ayude, tan solo debes buscar información sobre ello.  No pretendía enojarte, tan solo remarcar que en tu pregunta no se ve ningun intento de hacer lo que pretendes, y aquí procuramos arreglar errores de código, y no tienes ninguno ahora mismo.  Por eso te he indicado con enlaces lo que deberías hacer para que la pregunta sea mejor aceptada en la comunidad. Y no lo digo yo, lo dicen las normas que verás en los enlaces que te he puesto. Y mírate este tambien: [example]. Gracias

Comment: En cuanto al array `data` lo puedes manejar con un for de javascript normal y corriente... o con otras formas de tratar arrays en javascript. No necesitas el jquery para manejarlo, aunque si te ayudará en otras cosas con el método html() y sus selectores dentro del bucle que lo recorras.  Y si lo quieres sin "refrescar" tan solo debes hacerlo dentro del `success` y ya esta.

Comment: Listo bro! ya solucione, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro por ti.  Si no es mucha molestia puedes postear tu mismo la respuesta y así la comunidad sabrá como lo has podido solucionar y ayudar a quien tenga dudas semejantes, gracias!

Comment: dale bro, ya la subo

Answer (score 1):

Solución que conseguí, fue aplicar lo siguiente:
cree, un div con un id diferente

```
<div class="tab-pane fade d-none" id="v-pills-busqueda" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-busqueda-tab">
    <div id="accordion-busqueda" class="accordion-area">
    </div>
</div>
```

y desde jquery, luego de la peticion ajax, relleno el elemento div:

```
function buscar(){
    consulta = $("#search_faq_input").val();
    var url = '{{ route("front.buscarpreguntasfrecuentes", ":consulta") }}';
    url = url.replace(':consulta', consulta);
    var elemento = document.getElementById("v-pills-busqueda");

    $.ajax({
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: url,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#accordion-busqueda").empty();
            var filas = data.length;
            $("#v-pills-busqueda").removeClass("d-none");
            if (filas > 0) {
                for (  i = 0 ; i < filas; i++){
                    var nuevafila=
                    '<div class="panel"> <div class="panel-header" id="faq'+i+'">' +
                            '<button class="panel-link py-2 pl-1 px-2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse'+i+'" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse'+i+'">'+ data[i].pregunta +'</button>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div id="collapse'+i+'" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-administracion">' +
                            '<div class="panel-body px-3">'
                                + data[i].respuesta +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>';
                    $("#accordion-busqueda").append(nuevafila)
                }
                $("#v-pills-0").removeClass("show active");
                $("#v-pills-1").removeClass("show active");
                $("#v-pills-2").removeClass("show active");
                $("#v-pills-3").removeClass("show active");
                $("#v-pills-4").removeClass("show active");
                $("#v-pills-5").removeClass("show active");
                elemento.className += "show active";
            } else {
                var nuevafila= '<div class="alert alert-danger d-flex" role="alert"> <p class="mx-auto p-0"> Sin resultados </p> </div>';
                $("#accordion-busqueda").append(nuevafila)
                $("#v-pills-0").removeClass("show active");
                $("#v-pills-1").removeClass("show active");
                $("#v-pills-2").removeClass("show active");
                $("#v-pills-3").removeClass("show active");
                elemento.className += "show active";
            }

        },error:function(){
            console.log("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

doy uso  a las funciones jquery de remove class y className +, para  darle dinamismo a la vista, de tal forma que muestre las preguntas que se desea

Comment: Perfecto, y ya para terminar con el ciclo correcto de este sitio, en unas 24 horas creo que puedes marcarla como "Aceptada" y así ganará más visibilidad y la comunidad verá la solución que mejor te ha  funcionado. Para aprender a marcarla como aceptada puedes consultar [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200). Muchas gracias por tu colaboración, de verdad :-)

Comment: [¿Qué significa cuando una respuesta es "aceptada"?](/help/accepted-answer). No olvides aceptarla luego de 48 horas.