# php 5 + bootstrap modal

Tags: bootstrap, modal, php5

tengo un inconveniente al intentar pasar datos a un modal:

boton agregar al carito>

```
<a href="#" class="btn-producto" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#productosModal" data-image="<?php echo $root;?>/public/<?php echo $Producto['foto1']; ?>" data-title="<?php echo $Producto['producto']; ?>" >
    <img src="../assets/images/cart-3.svg" alt="">
    Agregar al carrito 
</a>
```

modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="productosModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="productosModal" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header border-bottom-0">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body rounded p-4">
        <div class="modal-addtocart position-relative">
        <h5 class="title-modal text-center mt-1">
            ¡Producto agregado a tu carrito!
        </h5>
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 text-center">
            <div>
                <div class="product-img-wrapper mb-2">
                <img src="" alt="">
                </div>
                <h5 class="title-producto-modal"></h5>
                <div>
                Cant: <span>1</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 text-center">
            <p class="cantidad-modal">Hay 1 artículos en tu carrito</p>
            
            <a class="btn-principal btn-catalogo-outline justify-content-center mt-3" href="<?php echo $root;?>catalogo.php">Ver más productos</a>
            <a href="<?php echo $root;?>carrito.php" class="btn-principal btn-catalogo justify-content-center mt-3">Comprar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

codigo jquery:

```
$('#productosModal').on('show', function(e) { 
    var link     = e.relatedTarget(),
        modal    = $(this),
        image    = link.data("image"),
        title    = link.data("title");

    modal.find("#card-image").val(image);
    modal.find("#card-title").val(title);
});
```

lo que estoy intentando hacer es que en el boton agregar al carrito, me muestre la modal con la imagen y titulo del producto, que estoy haciendo mal??

el boton agregar al carrito esta compuesto con un bucle for, la cual consulta a la base de datos y lista los productos que estan disponibles, alli no tengo inconvenientes, ya que me esta listando los productos disponibles, el unico inconveniente que estoy presentando es el de pasarle los datos a la modal, seria la imagen del producto y el titulo del producto, por cierto, tambien debo pasarle el id del producto

Comment: Acabo de agregar una respuesta. Recuerda marcar como aceptada tu [anterior autorespuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/525150/263200) (ya han pasado mas de 48 horas) y si mi respuesta a esta pregunta te vale entonces la mia tambien.  Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para capturar el evento show en bootstrap debes usar **show.bs.modal**, tal como se especifica en [su documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/#events), de este modo:

```
$('#productosModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
```

A partir de aquí ya puedes continuar con el resto de errores que te aparecerán, pues finalmente podrás ejecutar el contenido de ese **.on()**

Comment: gracias!!! funciono de una